# Set color of title-background

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to give the title (and the title only (with some margin), not the entire page) in the first page of my presentation background color "greyone". This background-box should be page-wide while text is centered. I haven't been able to figure out how to..

I've defined a new beamer template in my preamble by

```
\documentclass['serif]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{eelke}
% INFORMATION
\title{Presentation Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
% FRONTPAGE
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{eelke}[1]
{
\centering
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par % this should have a background box in color grayone. Text should be white for readability.
\vskip20pt
\usebeamercolor[bg]{titlelike}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\fontsize{11}{15}}
\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par %
\vskip20pt
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\fontsize{11}{15}}
\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par} \begin{document}\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}\end{document}
```

`

Further I have defined a new color in beamercolorthemeeelke.sty
file

```
\definecolor{greyone}{RGB}{77,77,77}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=greyone, wd=\paperwidth}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette quaternary}
```

which is called for in the preamble: \usecolortheme{eelke}

Can anyone help me out?

Edit: MAW added

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I've changed it to a compilable code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `beamercolorbox` but with `beamerleftmargin` and `beamerrightmargin` previously added to `textwidth`.

```
\documentclass['serif]{beamer}
%\usecolortheme{eelke}

\definecolor{greyone}{RGB}{77,77,77}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=greyone}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette quaternary}

% INFORMATION
\title{Presentation Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
% FRONTPAGE
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{eelke}[1]
{
\@tempdima=\textwidth%
\advance\@tempdima by \beamer@leftmargin%
\advance\@tempdima by \beamer@rightmargin%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\the\@tempdima]{titlelike}
\centering
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par % this should have a background box in color grayone. Text should be white for readability.
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip20pt
\usebeamercolor[bg]{titlelike}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\fontsize{11}{15}}
\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par %
\vskip20pt
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\fontsize{11}{15}}
\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]